# Is there any video format that is guaranteed to work in any web page?

Tags: html, video, codec

I want to include a video in a web presentation- conventionally we use simple hml files. Is there any video format that is guaranteed to  play on any computer?

If not, is there any video format that is guaranteed to play on any windows machine?

I have run into the problem that if I prepare the video in any of the common formats (MPG, wmv etc), and link to the video from the web page, that I will always come across a machine that does not have the correct codec installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MP4 with fallback on Flash (.FLV) would be my recommendation. Then you cover up pretty much every single device except Internet Explorer and Firefox without Flash installed.